# Redirect Back from uiweb view in gdata integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, gdata

I am making an application to integrate gmail to my app. I am able to login to gmail by gadata-objective c-client-1.11.0.a. I am giving the code

```
-(IBAction)googlelogin
{
    NSString *scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"; // scope for Google+ API

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope clientID:kMyClientID clientSecret:kMyClientSecret keychainItemName:nil delegate:self finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

    NSString *html = @"<html><body><div align=center>Loading sign-in page...</div></body></html>";
   [viewController setInitialHTMLString:html];

   [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];        

}
```

now i want to redirect back to my app after google login to get the contacts of gmail.  Help me how to generate taken and return back to my app after login

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should implement the method

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
             error:(NSError *)error {
 if (error != nil) {
  // Authentication failed
 }   else {
     // Authentication succeeded
   // here you should push your the root view controller of your app.
 }
```

}

Comment: can u help me with this error ---- Authentication error: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)"